# proxy.conf.json not working as expected in Angular 6

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, api, proxy

In my application I have a proxy.conf.json file to get around cors policy. Although there is no error for the console now. There seems to be an issue with returning the result. It gives my a 0 results in my json when I know the response has 50 albums on the itunes api.

**proxy.conf.json**

```
{
    "api": {
      "target": "https://itunes.apple.com/search?term=drake",
      "secure": true,
      "changeOrigin": true
    }
}
```

**service.ts**

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient, HttpEventType, HttpHeaders, HttpRequest, HttpResponse, HttpErrorResponse } from '@angular/common/http';
import { Observable, of, throwError } from 'rxjs';
import { catchError, retry } from 'rxjs/operators';


@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class ApiService {

  api: string = 'api';

  constructor(
    private http: HttpClient,
  ) { }

  getAll(): Observable<any> {
    return this.http.get<any>(this.api)
      .pipe(
        catchError(this.handleError)
      );
  }
  private handleError(error: HttpErrorResponse) {
    if (error.error instanceof ErrorEvent) {
      console.log(error.error.message)

    } else {
      console.log(error.status)
    }
    return throwError(
      console.log('Something is wrong!'));
  };
}
```

**component.ts**

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient, HttpEventType, HttpHeaders, HttpRequest, HttpResponse } from '@angular/common/http';
import { ApiService } from '../../../services/api.service';


@Component({
  selector: 'app-content',
  templateUrl: './content.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./content.component.scss']
})
export class ContentComponent implements OnInit {

  public results = [];
  public data = [];


  constructor(private service: ApiService) { }
  private http: HttpClient
  ngOnInit() {
    this.getApi();
  }


  private getApi() {
    this.service.getAll().subscribe((results) => {
      console.log('JSON Response = ', JSON.stringify(results));
      this.data = results.results;
    })
  }
}
```

ideas please?

Comment: why do you say its a proxy json issue

Comment: please see doc here `https://juristr.com/blog/2016/11/configure-proxy-api-angular-cli/`

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried with `/api` intead of just `api` ?

```
{
  "/api": {
    "target": {
      "host": "itunes.apple.com/search?term=drake"",
      "protocol": "https",
      "port": xxx
    },
    "secure": false,
    "changeOrigin": true
    "pathRewrite": {
      "^/api": ""
    }
  }
}
```